# Reverse method in Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I have done a lot of development to my linked list program.
When I want to reverse my list it says java heap space error(java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)

this is my reverse method:

```
    private void reverse()
    {
    Node start1=null;
    Node ptr1=start;
    while(ptr1!=null)
    {
        Node nnode=new Node();
        nnode.data=ptr1.data;

        if(isEmpty())
        {
            start1=nnode;
        }
        else
        {
            nnode.link=start1;
            start1=nnode;
        }
    }
    Node temp=start1;
    while(temp!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(temp.data);
        temp=temp.link;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you run out of memory is this loop:

```
while(ptr1!=null)
{
    Node nnode=new Node();
    nnode.data=ptr1.data;

    if(isEmpty())
    {
        start1=nnode;
    }
    else
    {
        nnode.link=start1;
        start1=nnode;
    }
}
```

It keeps creating new `Node`s until `ptr1` becomes `null`, yet it never advances the `ptr1`.

You need to either change the loop condition to check `start1`, or change the body of the loop to move `ptr1` to the next node.

Comment: I wasn't able to realise that.What and where should I add the command to advance ptr1?

Comment: Oh i got rid of the error. thank u so much for pointing out the mistake